# Lo que quiero hacer es que pueda poner "a@gmail.com"

Tags: python, tkinter

en la parte de las funciones, la de validacion quiero que cuando presione un boton vea si esta "@gmail.com" dentro del entry "e_correo"
el problema es que si escribo por ejemplo "a@gmail.com" no lo vale por la "a" y yo quiero que se ponga un correo alguien sabe que puedo hacer?esto lo hice con tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from turtle import color
import tkinter as tk


#ventana
ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.title("registracion")
ventana.geometry("700x550")
ventana.configure(background = "white smoke")

#Entrys
e_username = tk.Entry(ventana).place( y = 40,x = 13, width = 300, height = 25)
```

el entry de abajo

```
e_correo = tk.Entry(ventana)
e_contraseña = tk.Entry(ventana).place( y = 232,x = 13, width = 300, height = 25 )
e_correo.place( y = 140,x = 13, width = 300, height = 25)
```

justo aqui

```
#funciones
def validar():
if e_correo.get()== "@gmail.com":
    abrirventana2()
    else:
        messagebox.showwarning("cuidado","correo no valido")    

def abrirventana2():
    ventana.withdraw()
    win = tk.Toplevel()
    win.geometry("380x300+700+200")
    win.configure(background = "white smoke")
    e3 = tk.Label(win,text = "bienvenido", bg = "pink", fg = "white")
    e3.pack(padx=5,pady=5,ipadx=5,ipady=5,fill=tk.X)







#Label
Label(ventana, text = "Username",font = ("LEMON_MILK_Medium", 14) ,foreground = "blue",bg = 
"white smoke",  anchor = W, ). place(y = 8, x = 9)
Label(ventana, text = "Correo Electronico", font = ("LEMON_MILK_Medium", 14),foreground = 
"blue",bg = "white smoke",  anchor = W).place(y = 100, x = 9 )
Label(ventana, text = "Contraseña", font = ("LEMON_MILK_Medium", 14),foreground = "blue",bg = 
"white smoke",  anchor = W).place(y = 192, x = 9 )




#botones
```

este es el boton

```
boton_aceptar = Button(ventana, text = "terminar regristro", width = 30, height = 2, command = 
validar)
boton_aceptar.place(y = 500)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Si lo único que quieres es comprobar si el `string` de `e_correo` termina en "@gmail.com" puedes utilizar `endswith` (Más información [aquí](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/string-endswith#:%7E:text=The%20endswith()%20function%20returns,endswith()%20function%20returns%20True.))

```
str.endswith(suffix, start, end)
```

Pero en general, esta no es la forma correcta de validar un correo electrónico

Por ejemplo, si únicamente estas evaluando que contenga "@gmail.com" el `string` podría ser `ejemplo@gmail.com@prueba`. En este caso el string contiene "@gmail.com" pero no es un correo válido

Si únicamente evaluas si termina con "@gmail.com" con `endswith` entonces si el `string` es `ejemplo@prueba@gmail.com` retornaría que la validación es correcta pero sería un error ya que no es un correo válido

Para únicamente hacer lo que pides y ver si el correo incluye "@gmail.com" puedes hacer lo siguiente

```
if ('@gmail.com' in e_correo):
    print(True)
```

Pero, como mencioné anteriormente, el siguiente caso contaría como verdadero

```
if ('@gmail.com' in 'prueba@gmail.com@ejemplo'):
    print(True)
```

Si deseas únicamente comprobar si el `e_correo` termina en "@gmail.com" puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
if (e_correo.endswith('@gmail.com')):
    print(True)
```

Pero, como mencioné anteriormente, el siguiente caso contaría como verdadero:

```
if ('ejemplo@prueba@gmail.com'.endswith('@gmail.com')):
    print(True)
```

La forma correcta sería primero validar si `e_correo` en realidad cumple con el patron de ser un correo electrónico, para eso puedes utilizar expresiones regulares (Regex, del inglés Regular Expressions)

La siguiente función valida si un `string` es un correo o no

```
import re
 
# Expresion regular para validar un email en general
regex = r'\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z|a-z]{2,}\b'
 
# Función para saber si es un correo electrónico válido
def validarEmail(email):
  if(re.fullmatch(regex, email)):
    print("Válido")
  else:
    print("Inválido")

print(validarEmail('prueba@ejemplo@gmail.com'))
```

Por último, si únicamente quieres validar correos de "@gmail.com" y descartar todos los demás puedes modificar la expresión regular para validar únicamente "@gmailcom"

```
import re
 
# Expresion regular para validar un email en general
regex = r'\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@gmail.com\b'
 
# Función para saber si es un correo electrónico válido
def validarEmail(email):
  if(re.fullmatch(regex, email)):
    print("Válido")
  else:
    print("Inválido")

print(validarEmail('ejemplo@gmail.com')) #Regresa válido
print(validarEmail('ejemplo@hotmail.com')) #Regresa inválido
```

Comment: cuando le pongo al boton esa funcion del:if (e_correo.endswith('@gmail.com')):
    print(True) me manda este error:AttributeError: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'endswith'

Comment: Buen día, eso es porque `e_correo` es de tipo `tkinter.Entry()` y `endswith` es una propiedad de los `string` lo que puedes hacer es convertirlo a un string usando `str()` para validarlo `str_e_correo = str(e_coreo)`

Comment: ahora cuando lo hago un string directamente no pasa nada al presionar el boton

Comment: ??? ¿Qué hiciste string?

Comment: me equivoque, me fije y no habia puesto el else pero de igual manera cuando termino con un @gmail.com no me imprime el True

Comment: y lo que converti a string fue el `e_correo`

Comment: Pero `e_correo` lo pasas como string a otra variable? Es muy difícil adivinar qué estás haciendo. Mejor edita tu pregunta y agrega en la parte inferior lo que has agregado para poder ver que estás haciendo

Comment: lo puse asi `e_correo = str(e_correo)`

Comment: Ah, eso está mal, `e_correo` es tu variable que recibe `tk.Entry(ventana)` esa la necesitas para interactuar directamente con `tkinter`. Para validar el correo puedes utilizar otra variable, tal como lo puse en mi primer comentario a esta respuesta `str_e_correo = str(e_coreo)` y entonces evaluas `str_e_correo` o la otra forma si lo quieres hacer más directo puedes usar `str(e_correo).endswidth('@gmail.com')`

Comment: me pasa exactamente lo mismo te paso el codigo de nuevo pero con la funcion para que veas: `str_e_correo = str(e_correo)` esta es la funcion `def validarEmail():  
  if (str_e_correo.endswith('@gmail.com')):
    print(True)
  else:
    print(False)  
`

Comment: Ok, ya vi el problema: hace falta usar `.get()` en tu `e_correo`. Usa esto en el `if` `str(e_correo.get()).endswith('@gmail.com')`

Comment: al fin, muchas gracias master

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta por favor acéptala para que la pregunta quede resuelta y así ayudar a otros usuarios que tengan un problema similar. Al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas

Comment: ya esta aceptada

Comment: Como notaron str(entry) no devuelve el contenido del entry. Lo que devuelve es el path del widget. Ej: .!Toplevel.!Entry1

Comment: que es el path?